# Number of sftp connections allowed in a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, sftp

I understand that more than one SFTP connection is generally allowed. I would like to ask if this is possible even in a VM (virtual machine).
In other words, I would like to establish more than one SFTP connections in the same VM.

Note that the purpose of the vm is to give access to the storage space of a research team located in a cluster.

Comment: Do you currently experience that only one SFTP connection is allowed at a time? What operating system is the VM running and did you modify the way SSH and SFTP is configured on the VM?

Comment: The cluster uses centos7.
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release:        7.9.2009
Codename:       Core
No, the VM has not been created yet, as we are looking for the suitable conditions and requirements to create it.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the SFTP service, in its default configuration, will only ever allow a single connection at a time?  This would be an _unusual_ way of running a service, so it would be good to know why you are concerned about it.  In what way do you believe running an SFTP service on a VM is different from running an SFTP service on a bare metal machine? Note that the services on the VM will not know that they are running on a VM as opposed to a bare metal system.

Comment: @Kusalananda thus, I understand that the rules are exactly the same for the VM as for the bare metal service. So, I have only to keep in mind the case the sudoers of the cluster do not allow this. But, in general there is not any other limitation for >1 sftp connection in the same VM.
Many thanks, I have been fully covered.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the `sudoers` configuration has to do with this as running `sftp` is not something you would need special permissions to do.  Access restrictions to the SFTP service should be managed via the configuration of the SSH/SFTP service, not `sudo`.  The fact that you mention `sudo` leads me to believe that you may be _sharing_ SFTP credentials between users, which is quite obviously not the way to go about things.

Comment: It is a cluster of a lab of university. We would like to give access to some folders to external partners. Maybe the sudoers ( the IT of the university) have established rules about this. But, in general I think that my concerns have been covered. 
(vm is like a bare metal  system, thus normally >1 sftp are allowed)
I understand that is not the common case that the IT has rules about that, so I guess that we will not face any kind of issue about this.

Comment: Access should be given using SSH keys. Get the public SSH keys from the external partners. Turn off password authentication (and access to the root account!), and only give access to connections presenting the correct keys.   This way you can simply control who has access and you do not need to change a password every time you want to stop giving access to a particular person. The `sudo` utility should in no way be involved in this.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SFTP service running in a virtual machine will behave exactly like an SFTP service running on a bare metal server.  Both will accept multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: Perfectly yes exactly this. I understand from your answer and your comments, that the case that the IT of my university has rules about a VM is not likely to happen.